# NSUserDefaults synchronize fails when the application quits

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I’m using Xcode 8 under OS X 10.11.6 but the problem persists with Xcode 7. I have a main application and it’s helper, they share a group container.

```
prefsFile = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:kAppGroupName];
```

When I synchronize the NSUserDefaults during the session, all works fine but the helper needs to synchronize the preferences file when it receive the applicationShouldTerminate message : when the Mac shuts down or is restarted. It seems that synchronize in this case has no effect and is ignored. Not always but sometimes, randomly.

I always test the returned value of the method synchronize and this value is always YES. If NO, a message is sent to the log of the application.

Is there a way to solve the problem ?

Comment: maybe you should create a background task in that case to synchronize your  NSUserDefaults.